# excpetion on reception of incoming message in qpid cpp client

Tags: c++, amqp, qpid

First of all thanks for providing platform to discuss about issues.

I found issue with qpid cpp client program.

```
try{
cout << "Trying to open a connection" << endl;
connection.open("1.1.1.8", 10002);
session = connection.newSession();
SubscriptionManager subscriptions(session);
Listener listener(subscriptions);
subscriptions.subscribe(listener, receiver_queue);
//    subscriptions.run();
   subscriptions.start();
   sleep(10);
  }
 catch(const std::exception& error) {
  DEBUG(DBG_ERR, (char *)"AMQP-[%s]: Connection Error [%s].", __func__,error.what());
    connection.close();
   return RESULT_FAILURE;
 }
```

After   subscriptions.start, if I send any message to client program, i could see message is received but it failed with the following exception.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'qpid::Exception'
  what():  Invalid argument (../include/qpid/sys/posix/Mutex.h:116)
Aborted
```

Stack says..

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0024b424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x00276af1 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x002783ca in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x0026fdcb in __assert_fail_base () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x0026fe86 in __assert_fail () from /lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x00b683b6 in unlock (this=0x88501fc, name="A.B.ToApplication")
at ../include/qpid/sys/posix/Mutex.h:120
#6  ~ScopedLock (this=0x88501fc, name="A.B.ToApplication") 
at        .    ./include/qpid/sys/Mutex.h:34
#7  qpid::client::Dispatcher::find (this=0x88501fc,  
  name="A.B.ToApplication")
 at qpid/client/Dispatcher.cpp:137
#8  0x00b68752 in qpid::client::Dispatcher::run (this=0x88501fc) at    
qpid/client/Dispatcher.cpp:83
#9  0x00d5b701 in qpid::sys::(anonymous namespace)::runRunnable (p=0x88501fc) at 
qpid/sys/posix/Thread.cpp:35
#10 0x00564a09 in start_thread () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#11 0x0032915e in clone () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

Am i missing something here ?

please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use SubscriptionManager::start() - it is broken as it doesn't allow handling of exceptions - use SubscriptionManager::run() instead, spawning a new thread on which to do so if needed.

I would also strongly advise you to move to the qpid::messaging API instead of the old and now deprecated qpid::client API. The former is simpler and will allow easier transition to AMQP 1.0, and that is where all new development will occur.